# Using ffmpeg to join segments from multiple videos

Tags: ffmpeg, concatenation

We are trying to set up a process to let a user join together segments from multiple videos. Our process is set up to use ffmpeg to make separate mp4 files for each segment and to then to join them using the ffmpeg concat demuxer process. In generating the segment mp4 files, we are trying to make them all the same in terms of codex, dimensions, etc. so the concatenation will be successful. Here's an example of the call to create one of the segment mp4s.

```
ffmpeg -ss 0.5 -t 299.5 -i /tmp/vid1.mp4 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -framerate 29.97 -b:v 540k -maxrate 540k -minrate 540k -bufsize 540k -vf scale=640:480,fade=t=out:st=294.5:d=5 /tmp/vid1_new.mp4
```

This process works in some cases, but in others the joined file will play the first segment properly, but the later segments the video will sometimes freeze, or the audio will get speeded up. Does anyone have any suggestions for how to make the above ffmpeg command more "bullet-proof" so all the files will be compatible?

---

The command we use to concatenate files is:

```
/var/ffmpg/bin/ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i /tmp/files.txt -c copy /tmp/combined.mp4
```

The `ffprobe` output for one file is:

```json
{
  "format": {
    "filename": "vid2.mp4",
    "nb_streams": 2,
    "nb_programs": 0,
    "format_name": "mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2",
    "format_long_name": "QuickTime / MOV",
    "start_time": "0.000000",
    "duration": "1004.944000",
    "size": "109489681",
    "bit_rate": "871608",
    "probe_score": 100,
    "tags": {
      "major_brand": "isom",
      "minor_version": "512",
      "compatible_brands": "isomiso2avc1mp41",
      "encoder": "Lavf54.63.103"
    }
  }
}
```

The `ffprobe` output of the second file:

```json
{
  "format": {
    "filename": "vid1.mp4",
    "nb_streams": 2,
    "nb_programs": 0,
    "format_name": "mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2",
    "format_long_name": "QuickTime / MOV",
    "start_time": "0.000000",
    "duration": "1159.164000",
    "size": "63903454",
    "bit_rate": "441031",
    "probe_score": 100,
    "tags": {
      "major_brand": "isom",
      "minor_version": "512",
      "compatible_brands": "isomiso2avc1mp41",
      "encoder": "Lavf56.40.100"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is the concatenation portion of your command?  Have you read the documentation on the [`concat` filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat)?

Comment: Additionally, can you provide `ffprobe` output of files that do not concat together correctly as well as the `ffprobe` output of the concatenated file?  That could help narrow down the properties that either need to be adjusted or set in order to have files play nice together.

Comment: Yes I've read the concat documentation at [link](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate).

Here is the command we use to concatenate the files.

/var/ffmpg/bin/ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i /tmp/files.txt -c copy /tmp/combined.mp4

Comment: ffprobe for one file:
`"format": {
        "filename": "vid2.mp4",
        "nb_streams": 2,
        "nb_programs": 0,
        "format_name": "mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2",
        "format_long_name": "QuickTime / MOV",
        "start_time": "0.000000",
        "duration": "1004.944000",
        "size": "109489681",
        "bit_rate": "871608",
        "probe_score": 100,
        "tags": {
            "major_brand": "isom",
            "minor_version": "512",
            "compatible_brands": "isomiso2avc1mp41",
            "encoder": "Lavf54.63.103"
        }
    }
`

Comment: ffprobe for 2nd file: `"format": {
        "filename": "vid1.mp4",
        "nb_streams": 2,
        "nb_programs": 0,
        "format_name": "mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2",
        "format_long_name": "QuickTime / MOV",
        "start_time": "0.000000",
        "duration": "1159.164000",
        "size": "63903454",
        "bit_rate": "441031",
        "probe_score": 100,
        "tags": {
            "major_brand": "isom",
            "minor_version": "512",
            "compatible_brands": "isomiso2avc1mp41",
            "encoder": "Lavf56.40.100"
        }
    }`